# The unique Rule validation is not applied

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 9.
And I have this very simple validation rule (form request validation):

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:50',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:50',
            'email' => [
                'email',
                Rule::unique('unknown_table')->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('library_id', $this->library->id);
                })
            ],
.......
```

What I do not understand is why my post is working with this table name "unknown_table", because this table really does not exist. I expected an exception but nothing happens !

Is this rule correctly written ?

Comment: Rule::unique call only when if you supply email id or else it wont exicute

Comment: When I debug, the "email" attribute is present.

Comment: you should have value in it. if its empty then rule unique wont check.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood my error. The "email" validation was twice in the rule array ! And it was the last one which was used of course.